Custom rectangle through css
custom rectangle
I'm trying to recreate a similar shape using CSS, specifically with border-radius and clip-path, but I'm having trouble getting it to look right
I've previously attempted using the canvas element to achieve this, but I’d like to find a simpler and more efficient CSS-based approach if possible. Could someone guide me on how to use border-radius and clip-path properties together, or suggest any alternative CSS techniques to create this shape effectively

https://css-shape.com/inverted-radius/

if it doesn't have some content. Will be better if you create svg element from figma and use it. For example:
<svg width="244" height="244" viewBox="0 0 244 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M2 22V222C2 233.046 10.9543 242 22 242H222C233.046 242 242 233.046 242 222V142C242 130.954 233.046 122 222 122H142C130.954 122 122 113.046 122 102V22C122 10.9543 113.046 2 102 2H22C10.9543 2 2 10.9543 2 22Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear_301_3)" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear_301_3" x1="242" y1="21.6144" x2="52.9557" y2="262.393" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#072515"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#000C02"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>

